# upload a specific file form Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement, file-upload

I just have a upload file form in my django project (I'm using 1.10). Everything is working pretty fine actually, but as people will be uploading a csv file into the server I need to limit my logic into just request the file with a specific name and format.

This is my code:

**views.py**

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('action'))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                             'Something went wrong with files! Please contact the system administrator')
        return render(request, 'upaction-report.html')

    # Load documents for the list page

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request, 'upaction-report.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='File format should be under the following format:',
        help_text='- .csv format and under the name "Action_Report"',
    )
```

**template html**

```
<form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

    <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }}</p>
    <p> {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>


    <p>

        {{ form.docfile }}
    </p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload File"/></p>
</form>
```

Any guess on how applying that limit? In case the file is not the right just to pop up a message telling to try again until it has the right format and name. Thanks for yout time, if you need more details just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate filename inside DocumentForm `clean` method like this:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='File format should be under the following format:',
        help_text='- .csv format and under the name "Action_Report"',
    )

    def clean(self):
        docfile = self.cleaned_data.get('docfile')
        if not docfile:
            raise forms.ValidationError('file is required')  
        if not docfile.name.startswith('filename'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('incorrect file name')
        if not docfile.name.endswith('fileformat'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('incorrect file format')
        return super(DocumentForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: Hi neverwalkaloner, thanks for your time. were exactly should I set up this? into my views.py?

Comment: @Deluq no you should try it inside DocumentForm class. I updated my answer.

Comment: oh alright, got it. I'm getting this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'. should I set the filename and fileformat somewhere?

Comment: @Deluq did you select any file? I suppose you see this error because no file has been chosen. What you need to do is also validate if docfile is None.  See updated answer.

Comment: oh alright now is working, but stil having the doubt. were do I declare which should be the file name and the file format?

Comment: should I declare them as docfile? and just state the file name and format as string?

Comment: @Deluq inside clean method. You can just insert csv as file format and Action_report as filename.

Comment: @Deluq yes you just state filename and fileformat as string.

Comment: this way?         if not docfile.name.startswith('Action_report'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('incorrect file name')
        if not docfile.name.endswith('csv'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('incorrect file format')

Comment: @Deluq yes, that is right. Just insert your filename and csv as format.